# It crashes when clicking the link of webview in iOS 13

Tags: ios

When the link in webview with clicking, there is no response. When the link with long press, it crash with the **message:**

```
Trapped uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '_UIClickPresentationInteraction cannot determine presenting view controller.'
```

---

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98bde __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff503b5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98958 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff255eb6f5 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff470cf0fd -[_UIClickPresentationInteraction _canPerformPresentation] + 431
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff470d16eb -[_UIClickPresentationInteraction _handleTransitionToPreview] + 136
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff470d1046 __55-[_UIClickPresentationInteraction _prepareStateMachine]_block_invoke_3 + 35
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471f0fb0 -[_UIStateMachine handleEvent:withContext:] + 412
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff470cff63 -[_UIClickPresentationInteraction clickInteractionDidClickUp:] + 55
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46dd5aed -[_UIClickInteraction clickDriver:didPerformEvent:] + 316
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46a3831f __58-[_UILongPressClickInteractionDriver _prepareStateMachine]_block_invoke_2 + 74
11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471f0fb0 -[_UIStateMachine handleEvent:withContext:] + 412
12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46a38e04 -[_UILongPressClickInteractionDriver _updateForActiveGestureRecognizer] + 673
13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46a38a59 -[_UILongPressClickInteractionDriver _handleGestureRecognizer:] + 382
14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46d1e777 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 44
15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46d27909 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46d24fc5 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 298
17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46d242f2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents] + 757
18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46d16308 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 2700
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afaeb7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af594e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af5fca __CFRunLoopRun + 1514
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af56b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
23  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff3815cbb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47162a67 UIApplicationMain + 1621
25  IBUWireless                         0x000000010b372728 main + 296
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5123bcf5 start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

**iOS13 OS**

Answer (score 0):

I have recently fixed this issue and solved by setting

```
    webviewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

    self.present(webviewcontroller, animated: animated, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But it is a inner link in WKWebview and the present operation is controled by webview. So do you have any idea in the situation.

Comment: Embed your webview in **viewcotroller**, and set **viewcotroller**'s modalPresentationStyle.

Comment: Our webview is added to the window. So there isn't a viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Webview has been depricated so You must use WKWebView.

Note

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the WKPreferences property javaScriptEnabled to false if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript.

Read WkWebView
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

Comment: Yeah, we are using WKWebView.

Comment: And you can save cookies with WKWebView for local reload the view in better way

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a cookies' problem. It crashes in the system library.